# terraform - how to update route_table attribute conditionally

Tags: terraform

any ideas how to conditionally insert 'propagating_vgws = some_vgw' ??

I see lots of ways to conditionally create a resource, but what about a resources optional attribute?

```
resource "aws_route_table" "internal" {
  count  = "${length(var.internal_subnets)}"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
#  propagating_vgws = ["${aws_vpn_gateway.main.id}"]

  tags {
    Name = "${var.name}-${format("internal-%03d", count.index+1)}"
  }
}
```

the route_table is created by a vpc module and I need to conditionally place that vpc on a direct-connect virtual interface or not.

thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html) will help you. (scroll to the conditinals section).

The idea is that you can do a conditional interpolation, and you can create an empty list rendering the attribute empty, thus in a way optional (has meaningful value or not):

```
propagating_vgws = "${var.decide_based_on_this_value == var.something ?
                      var.list_in_case_yes : list() }"
```

`${list()}` returns an empty list, for more refer to the above linked page, at the bottom there are many built-in functions like lists...

I hope it will solve your problem.